# Simplifying equation with summation and integrals

Tags: integration, summation, random-variables, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be a uniformly distributed random variable between 0 and 10. Also let $Y$ be exponentially distributed with $\lambda=1$. I want to solve the following equation where $\tau\geq 0$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{(i-1)\tau}^{i\tau}\int_{(i-1)\tau}^{t}tf_{X}(x)f_{Y}(t-x)dxdt+i\tau\int_{(i-1)\tau}^{\tau}\left(1-F_{Y}(i\tau-x)\right)f_{X}(x)dx\right)$$
I now use that $f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{10}, F_{Y}(x)=1-e^{-x}$ and $f_{Y}(x)=e^{-x}$ to get the equation,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{(i-1)\tau}^{i\tau}\int_{(i-1)\tau}^{t}\frac{t}{10}e^{-t+x}dx dt + i\tau\int_{(i-1)\tau}^{i\tau}e^{-i\tau+x}\cdot\frac{1}{10}dx\right).$$
I first compute the double integral to be
$$\int_{(i-1)\tau}^{i\tau}\int_{(i-1)\tau}^{t}\frac{t}{10}e^{-t+x}dxdt=\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{2i\tau^{2}-\tau^{2}}{2}-1+e^{-\tau}-i\tau+i\tau^{-\tau}+\tau\right),$$
and the other integral,
$$i\tau\int_{(i-1)\tau}^{i\tau}e^{-i\tau+x}\cdot\frac{1}{10}dx=\frac{i\tau}{10}\left(1-e^{-\tau}\right).$$
This means I now need to solve the summation,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{2i\tau^{2}-\tau^{2}}{2}-1+e^{-\tau}-i\tau+i\tau^{-\tau}+\tau\right)+\frac{i\tau}{10}\left(1-e^{-\tau}\right)\right).$$
This can be simplified to,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{2i\tau^{2}-\tau^{2}}{2}-1+e^{-\tau}+\tau\right)\right).$$
This is the point where I get stuck. From looking at the sum I get the idea that this is a diverging sum, which should not be the case. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: @user170231 I'm sorry. I am not sure what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, what I commented earlier didn't seem totally relevant in hindsight. Your evaluation looks to be on the right track. It might be illuminating to mention why this expression is of interest (i.e. what does it represent? why sum over $i\in\Bbb N$?)